# React clone component (stateless or stateful) to pass additional props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to clone/extend a React component (without knowing if it is statefull or stateless) and pass it props:

```
const Foo = (props) => {
    return (
    <div>foo</div>
  );
}

class Bar extends React.Component {
    render() {
    return (
        <div>bar</div>
    )
  }
}
```

The problem is, these two variables `Foo` and `Bar` should be handled differently:

```
const FooExtended = (props, context) => {
    return Foo(_.extend(props, additionalProps), context);
}

class BarExtended extends Bar {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(_.extend(props, additionalProps), context);
    }
}
```

And there is no simple way to know if a variable `Component` is Stateless or Statefull without doing hacky `toString` regex tests.

`React.cloneElement/createElement` fails on these giving me the following error:

> React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for
>   built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)
>   but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the
>   file it's defined in.

So is there a simple way that I can do just `cloneComponent(originalComponent, additionalProps)`?

Comment: https://shripadk.github.io/react/docs/clone-with-props.html check this out

Comment: @SterlingArcher this API is deprecated and `React.cloneElement` gives me the error I posted in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And there is no simple way to know if a variable Component is Stateless or Statefull [...]

And I think this is one of the reasons why it was required to `extend React.Component` at some point, to make it easier to distinguish between those two. Because React itself has to be able to distinguish between them since `class`es cannot be instantiated without `new`.

You could do the following:

```js
function cloneComponent(originalComponent, additionalProps) {
   if (originalComponent.prototype instanceof React.Component) {
     return class extends originalComponent {
       constructor(props, context) {
         super(_.extend(props, additionalProps), context);
       }
     };
   }
   return (props, context) => {
     return originalComponent(_.extend(props, additionalProps), context);
   };
}
```

Because `Foo.protoype instanceof React.Component` is `true`.

---

**However**, I think it is more common to do something like this instead:

```
function addProps(Component, additionalProps) {
  return props => <Component {...props} {...additionalProps} />;
}
```

Then there is no need to distinguish between stateful and stateless components.

Comment: The `instanceof` does not work, which in turn really confuses me https://jsfiddle.net/yr32quya/.

Comment: Also, I like `addProps` but then what about the context?

Comment: You are doing `Bar instanceof ...` where it should be `Bar.prototype instanceof ...`. Context is passed automatically afaik.

Comment: Ah I see; thanks for all the help This was very educational!

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa: Why do you think that?